# Python - SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED when connecting to DigitalOcean

Tags: python, redis

I'm using [aioredis](https://aioredis.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) to connect to my DigitalOcean Redis database and establish a pubsub connection from my local machine to the DigitalOcean DB. The problem with my code is that i keep getting this error:

```
[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: certificate has expired (_ssl.c:1108)
```

Here is the code:

```
import asyncio

import async_timeout

import aioredis

async def reader(channel: aioredis.client.PubSub):
    while True:
        try:
            async with async_timeout.timeout(1):
                message = await channel.get_message(ignore_subscribe_messages=True)
                if message is not None:
                    print(f"(Reader) Message Received: {message}")
                    if message["data"] == STOPWORD:
                        print("(Reader) STOP")
                        break
                await asyncio.sleep(0.01)
        except asyncio.TimeoutError:
            pass

async def main():
    redis = aioredis.from_url("rediss://<MY-USER>:<MY-PASS>@<REDIS-DB>.b.db.ondigitalocean.com:25061")
    pubsub = redis.pubsub()
    await pubsub.subscribe("test")

    asyncio.create_task(reader(pubsub))


asyncio.run(main())
```

Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: As you are using rediss (SSL), you can try setting ssl_cert_reqs to None
```aioredis.from_url(redis_url, ssl_cert_reqs=None)```

Ref: Heroku Docs, https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/connecting-heroku-redis#connecting-in-python